# Spring MVC File upload return - 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm writing a web service to upload a image/video file to the server. Every time I call my upload web service from postman, it return **415 Unsupported Media Type**.
Here is what I have done.

In my controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile files) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder rb;

    rb = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
    rb.entity(new ResponseWrapper<String>(SUCCESS, ""));
    return rb.build();
}
```

application context:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

I have already added   `commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar` & `mimepull.jar`

When I call the web service I get the following console log.

```
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, and Java type interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------410903058421289672087091 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
multipart/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

I've tried many things digging the internet, still dosnt'e work. Help is appreciated.

Comment: set a content type header in rb

Comment: Are you posting from a HTML form?

Comment: @ScaryWombat no, its a mobile api

Comment: @DevZer0 still getting the same error, matter fact it does't go inside the method body.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the content type using the following format

```
rb.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

change the media type accordingly to your needs. text_plain as provided in the example above should be setting `text/plain`

Comment: still getting the same error, matter fact it does't go inside the method body.

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes in suggest:

1. Change `@produces` to `@consumes` as this api is accepting the file which is `multipart/form-data`.
2. Change @RequestParam to @RequestPart

Comment: Still same error. I think there is something to do with spring configurations or something. because when I debug, it dosn't even hit the method.

Comment: It might happen that this method is not inside the `@controller` class or the package in which this class resides might not be scanned by the `@configuration` class. If you don't mind,  share the configuration of the project.

Comment: All the other request in the controller is working fine. So there can't be any issue in there.

Comment: Have you configured `MultipartResolver` in your configuration?

Comment: I haven't done anything other than what I've posted which is related to file uploading, so I guess I hven't. Do you have any example?

Comment: I have followed this example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Comment: Have try this one. It works fine when I upload file from the webpage through HTML. Trouble is when I call it from the external API (postman).